# BIOS constantly clearing

Tags: motherboard, bios

I have old 12 years montherboard. It's DFi Lanparty Ultra-D. I'm using it for mining which works perfect, BUT BIOS is not holding it's settings.
I've replaced battery, I've also tried to "play" with jumper for reset settings, but still the same.

When PC is powered on, settings are remembered. Once when AC power shut down, whole BIOS settings became default.

Can you please help me, what can cause this problem ?
Thank you!!

Comment: Maybe the battery is upside down?

Comment: Check motherboard for physical signed of damage such as swollen capacitors with dust or ooze coming out of them or just swollen. Look for heat checked and char marks with soot, etc. too. Battery seems like the likely culprit so try with another battery and put a voltmeter to read voltage from battery and see what it shows.

Comment: Wish this will help ... no, it's in correct position

Comment: Oki, I will try to check capacitors and measure the voltage, but it's new battery

Comment: No it didn't help

*** I've changed battery for new one, measured it's voltage, 3V 
*** I've measured voltage on pins connected to the battery - check if battery is charging - 3V on powered MB
*** I've checked whole board, looks almost like new, no scratches, no rusty or damaged capacitors
*** I'm desperate